# hashing password using md5 and a control field

Tags: java, android, md5

I want to hash a password using MD5 and I have given a string named *MD5ControlHash*
I found that I can hash a password in this way:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
    {
        String password = "123456";

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(password.getBytes());

        byte byteData[] = md.digest();

        //convert the byte to hex format method 1
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
         sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }

        System.out.println("Digest(in hex format):: " + sb.toString());
}
```

However I don't know where should I use *MD5ContolHash*. Can anyone help me?
Does this code work correctly?

Thanks

Comment: I sure hope you're not using MD5 as a password hash in any "serious" code...

Answer (score 0):

If *MD5ControlHash* is a string, where should be stored hash of the password, you need to replace this line of code:

```
System.out.println("Digest(in hex format):: " + sb.toString());
```

with

```
MD5ControlHash = sb.toString();
```

If this string called *MD5ControlHash* stores the source data to hash, just use *MD5ControlHash* instead of *password*
And if you doubt about correctness of the code, just try it out!

Comment: No. The documentation says that MD5ControlHash is a field that is needed to hash password. (MD5ControlHash is sent from server)

Comment: Then maybe you should write resulting hash to MD5ControlHash? And get password from some another field?